# Where do I put PHP to get a term ID?

Tags: 6, taxonomy-terms

I've been trying to figure our how to get a term ID of a taxonomy term I created, and I found a little bit of php that looks like it should work. However I have no idea where to put it to get a response.

I'm working on a D6 site that needed updating and already found this script

```
$term = taxonomy_get_term($tid);
$name = $term->name;
```

Any pointers?

Comment: A little additional info. I'm just trying to create a view and need the taxonomy id of a term to add as a filter.

Comment: Are you creating a view with Views or are you using hook_node_view()?

Comment: I'm creating a view with views, and I need to pull in multiple terms from different taxonomies, so I figured using the taxonomy ID would work best.

Comment: If you load nodes in the view all taxonomy terms are allready associated with it. so there is no problem?

Comment: Haha well thats what I'm trying to do. Add the nodes by using the TID. ...the below answer worked for me though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code won't work.  The first line is using the `$tid` to load the term, obviously that won't work if you don't know the Term ID in the first place.

You don't need to use any PHP to get a taxonomy terms ID. Just goto the edit page of that term and look at the url. It will be `/taxonomy/term/TID/edit`

Comment: Ahh I didn't realize this was in there! Thanks for the help!